# np.where() with np.linspace()

Tags: numpy-ndarray, linspace

I am trying to find index of an element in x_norm array with np.where() but it doesn' t work well.
Is there a way to find index of element?

```
x_norm  = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
np.where(x_norm == -0.19019019)
```

Np.where works with np.arange() and can find the index either first or last element of array creating by linspace.

Comment: maybe it would be better to use `np.argmin(np.abs(x_norm-yournumber))` so it would find the nearest value?

Comment: Thank you so much, it's exactly helpful and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers generated by `np.linspace` contains more decimal places than the one you are pasting to np.where (-0.19019019019019012).

So it might be better to  use `np.argmin` to find the nearest value and avoid rounding errors:

```
x_norm  = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
yournumber=-0.19019019
idx=np.argmin(np.abs(x_norm-yournumber))
```

You can then go further and add `np.where(x_norm==x_norm[idx])` to your code in case if you'll have array with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Set the level of precision to 8 using np.round then use np.where to filter data as a mask then apply the mask to the array.

```
x_norm  = np.round(np.asarray(np.linspace(-10,10,1000)),8)
results=x_norm[np.where(x_norm==-9.91991992)]
print(results)
```